# Special characters in ajax function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i have a simple question
i made a jQuery ajax function that get some html from another php page.
I'm new with ajax and php and i don't know them very well.
This is my ajax code:

```
function searchFilm(query){
$.get("search.php", {search: query}, function(data)  {$("#replace_film").replaceWith(data);});
}
```

And the search.php page has some code like this:

```
$link = mysql_connect("host","user","pass");
mysql_select_db("film",$link);
$search = $_GET['search'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM film WHERE titolo LIKE '%$search%' ORDER BY id DESC",$link) or die("Errore");
echo "some information about film... (html code)";
mysql_close($link);
```

It works pretty good but there is a little problem in fact when in the text there are some characters like these àòèù it returns this character: �

Then i call the function searchFilm with onkeyup on an input text.

Comment: note related... but....consider do not using "SELECT * FROM" in your $query statements, instead mentions your column name "SELECT * FROM"

Comment: @GibboK Ok thanks for the tip!

Comment: regarding your question ... have you checked if your php code returns ut8? this could cause your issue.

Comment: problem is definitely related to data not being charset utf-8. Check database settings

Comment: In the page where i call the ajax function i put the same code to retrieve the data from the database but without using ajax and the text is correct. Do i have to use utf8_encode () function?